# If you capture sports data by yourself, is it legal to publish it and use commercialy?

Tags: statistics

Let's suppose I capture some sports statistics - for example, all made shots for players on a team in the NBA. Can I publish that data and maybe use it commercially later?

Answer (score 4):

There were some legal processes that considered sports scores and other data as facts, and consequently, allowing its usage by commercial applications or being published.

Based my answer on the follow Legal Stack Exchange reply: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11081/is-there-copyright-on-sporting-results/11090#11090